# Determine inversible operator

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I determine if the linear operator $f: P_2 \rightarrow P_2, f(p) = p+p'+p''$ is invertible? 
I suppose that I should find a function that is undoing $f$ but I don't know if there is some preferred way of doing that.

EDIT

$P_2$ is all polynomials of power up to 2.

Comment: Can you tell us what $P_2$ is?

Comment: Write $p$ explicitly in the form $ax^2+bx+c$ and try to prove that $\text{ker}(f)=\{0_{P_2}\}$. Alternatively prove directly that $f(p)=f(q)\implies p=q$ for all $p,q\in P_2$.

Comment: Added $P_2$ description now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what $f$ does to the basis $\{1, t, t^2 \}$ of $P_2$.  Since

$f(p(t)) = p(t) + p'(t) + p''(t), \tag{1}$

we have

$f(1) = 1, \tag{2}$

$f(t) = t + 1, \tag{3}$

and

$f(t^2) = t^2 + 2t + 2.  \tag{4}$

$1$, $t + 1$, and $t^2 + 2t + 2$ are lineary independent; this may be seen my simply noting they are of different degrees, or to be more explicit, by writing

$a(t^2 + 2t + 2) + b(t + 1) + c \cdot 1 = 0 \tag{5}$

for some non-zero $a$, $b$, $c$.  We see from (5) that we must have $a = 0$, since it is the only coefficient of $t^2$.  But then we have $b = 0$, since it is the coefficient of $t$ in what is left over from (5) after setting $a = 0$; that $c = 0$ similarly follows.  Thus the set $\{ 1, t + 1, t^2 + 2t + 2 \}$ is linearly independent, and since it consists of three vectors in the three-dimensional vector space $P_2$, it is a basis.  Thus $f$ maps the basis $\{1, t, t^2 \}$ to the basis $\{1, t + 1, t^2 + 1 \}$; as such it is invertible.  And this discussion shows a way to establish the invertability of $f$ (showing $f$ maps a basis to a basis), thus answering theva's question.

It is also pretty easy to find a linear map $g:P_2 \to P_2$ which "is undoing" $f$, i.e., such that $g(f(p(t)) = p(t)$, since from $2$ we must have

$g(1) = g(f(1)) = 1, \tag{6}$

and thus using (3)

$g(t) = g((t + 1) - 1) = g(t + 1) - g(1) = gf(t) - g(1) = t - 1; \tag{7}$

we see from (6) and (7) that

$g(t + 1) = g(t) + g(1) = t - 1 + 1 = t, \tag{8}$

as it should.  Finally, we have

$g(t^2) = g((t^2 + 2t + 2) - 2(t + 1)) = g(f(t^2) - 2f(t))$
$= gf(t^2) - 2gf(t) = t^2 - 2t. \tag{9}$

We check:

$g(t^2 + 2t + 2) = g(t^2) + 2g(t) + 2g(1) = t^2 - 2t + 2t -2 + 2 = t^2, \tag{10}$

also as expected.  $g$ "undoes" $f$.

One can aslo proceed using matrices, as did Ivo Terek.  It is easy to see that his matrix

$F = \begin{bmatrix} 1& 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \tag{11}$

represents $f$ in the $\{1, t, t^2 \}$ basis; it is easy to see that $\det F = 1$; thus $F$ is an invertible matrix and hence $f:P_2 \to P_2$ an invertible linear map.  We may with relative ease compute the inverse $G = F^{-1}$ of $F$ by observing that

$F = I + N, \tag{12}$

where

$N = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag{13}$

we note that $N$ is in fact nilpotent:

$N^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \tag{14}$

and

$N^3 = 0. \tag{15}$

We use these facts along with the identity

$(1 + a)(1 -a + a^2 + \ldots + (-a)^m) = 1 + (-a)^{m + 1} \tag{16}$

(which holds for any unital ring), to see that

$F(I - N + N^2) = I; \tag{17}$

this allows us to conclude that

$G = I - N + N^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1& 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} =$
$ = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}; \tag{18}$

It is easy to see that $G$ is the matrix of the operator $g$ presented above.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: @theva:  Thank ***you***!  Glad you liked it!  And thanks for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Look at the matrix of $f$ in the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ of $\mathcal{P}_2$. You have: $$\begin{cases} f(1) = 1+(1)'+(1)'' = 1 &= 1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0\cdot x^2 \\ f(x) = x + (x)'+(x)'' = x+1 &= 1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 \\ f(x^2) = x^2 + (x^2)' + (x^2)'' = x^2 + 2x + 2 &= 2 \cdot 1+ 2 \cdot x + 1 \cdot x^2\end{cases}.$$ Is the matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ invertible?